# Why isn't this query finding all of the song with an A?

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to search al song with an A in my DB but for some reasing not all songs show up.
Does anyone know?

```
SELECT Song.Titel, Artist.ArtistName, Song_Playlist.PlaylistID
FROM Song INNER JOIN Song_Playlist ON Song.ID = Song_Playlist.SongID
  LEFT JOIN Song_artist ON Song.ID = Song_artist.SongID
  LEFT JOIN Artist ON Artist.ID = Song_artist.ArtistID 
WHERE Song.Titel LIKE '%a%'
```

[Contents of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BiEa.png)

[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ObO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using of INNER JOIN causes query to show records from Song table that have corresponding entry in Song_Playlist table.
My guess is that there are no records in Song_Playlist table for missing songs.

Comment: oh yeah i see it know, just a stupid mistaken on the friday morning

Answer (score 0):

In place of INNER JOIN try using LEFT JOIN, because INNER JOIN returns result if it finds matching rows in both sides of the table.

INNER JOIN depends on the rows of the Song and Song_artist, and you have not provided the rows of these 2 tables.

So try using LEFT JOIN.